# Xcode 8 Can not build with carthage

Tags: xcode, carthage

I'm migrating my project from 7.3.1 to 8.0, and I have some code written in old version of Swift, so I set Use Legacy Swift Language Version to YES. When I build and run, I get this:

`Module file was created by an older version of the compiler; rebuild 'Charts' and try again`

This is kind of Swift compatibility problems, then I use `carthage update --no-use-binaries`, and I get error from xcodebuild.

See below for details

*`carthage version`: 0.18-19-g743fa0f
*`xcodebuild -version`: Xcode 8.0 Build version 8A218a
*Are you using `--no-build`? NO
*Are you using `--no-use-binaries`? YES
*Are you using `--use-submodules`? NO

**Cartfile**

`github "SnapKit/SnapKit" >= 0.15.0
github "danielgindi/Charts" == 2.3.0
github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa"`

**Carthage Output**

`*** Fetching ReactiveCocoa
*** Fetching Charts
*** Fetching SnapKit
*** Fetching Result
*** Fetching realm-cocoa
*** Checking out realm-cocoa at "v1.1.0"
*** Checking out Charts at "v2.3.0"
*** Checking out Result at "2.1.3"
*** Checking out ReactiveCocoa at "v4.2.2"
*** Checking out SnapKit at "3.1.0"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/n4/ly193t_d7d1326f41qn6d7fr0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.xnRGEX.log
*** Building scheme "Realm" in Realm.xcworkspace
2016-10-08 17:10:14.761 xcodebuild[18149:896423] [MT] DVTPlugInManager: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 8A66E736-A720-4B3C-92F1-33D9962C69DF for KSImageNamed.ideplugin (com.ksuther.KSImageNamed) not present
A shell task (/usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -workspace /Users/jieding/Desktop/hfsparent/Carthage/Checkouts/SnapKit/SnapKit.xcworkspace -scheme "SnapKit OSX" -configuration Release CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES clean -showBuildSettings) failed with exit code 66:
2016-10-08 17:10:34.535 xcodebuild[18361:897289] [MT] DVTPlugInManager: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 8A66E736-A720-4B3C-92F1-33D9962C69DF for KSImageNamed.ideplugin (com.ksuther.KSImageNamed) not present
xcodebuild: error: Scheme SnapKit OSX is not currently configured for the clean action.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved here [Xcode 8 Can not build with carthage #1520](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1520)